# Retrofit-Kotlin NullPointerException on non-null object type

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I am facing a really weird issue while implementing GitHub API's using `Retrofit` and `Kotlin`.

This is my first time working on Andorid Arch and `Retrofit` so pardon me if i make any mistake in this question.

What exactly is happening is i am calling a GitHub API using `Retrofit` to fetch user's repositories. One repo have `null` in `description`. My app doesn't crash on that time when API returns null, it crashes when i am passing that object in `Intent` to another `Activity`. My Data Class is `Parcelable`.

Below is my Data Class:

```
data class GitHubRepository(
    var id: String = "",
    var name: String = "",
    var full_name: String = "",
    var owner: GitHubUser = GitHubUser(),
    var description: String = "",            // This is getting null even when it is of non-null type
    var html_url: String = "",
    var watchers_count: String = ""
) : Parcelable {
constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readParcelable(GitHubUser::class.java.classLoader),
        parcel.readString(),                // This is where i am getting error
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString())

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(id)
        parcel.writeString(name)
        parcel.writeString(full_name)
        parcel.writeParcelable(owner, flags)
        parcel.writeString(description)
        parcel.writeString(html_url)
        parcel.writeString(watchers_count)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<GitHubRepository> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): GitHubRepository {
            return GitHubRepository(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<GitHubRepository?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Below is how i am creating Retrofit object:

```
val BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/"

private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

fun getClient(): Retrofit {

    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
    }

    return retrofit!!
}
```

Below is My API Request:

```
@GET("users/{username}/repos")
fun getReposOfUser(
        @Path("username") username: String,
        @Query("page") pageNumber: Int,
        @Query("per_page") perPage: Int = 10
): Call<ArrayList<GitHubRepository>>
```

API that have `null` value in description:
https://api.github.com/users/kislyuk/repos

Below is the Response:

```
[
...
{
    "id": 1924281,
    "name": "akutils",
    "full_name": "kislyuk/akutils",
    "owner": {...},
    "private": false,
    "html_url": "https://github.com/kislyuk/akutils",
    "description": null, // This is the null value
    ...
}
...
]
```

Below is the LogCat in which `GitHubModels.kt` is my **Kotlin file** which contains other data classes as well. The one with error is `GitHubRepository` data class which i displayed above:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tarunchauhan.githubapp, PID: 18276
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tarunchauhan.githubapp/com.tarunchauhan.githubapp.activities.RepoDetailsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: parcel.readString() must not be null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: parcel.readString() must not be null
        at com.tarunchauhan.githubapp.models.GitHubRepository.<init>(GitHubModels.kt:29)
        at com.tarunchauhan.githubapp.models.GitHubRepository$CREATOR.createFromParcel(GitHubModels.kt:49)
        at com.tarunchauhan.githubapp.models.GitHubRepository$CREATOR.createFromParcel(GitHubModels.kt:47)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2781)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2675)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3042)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:257)
        at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:888)
        at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:7075)
        at com.tarunchauhan.githubapp.activities.RepoDetailsActivity.onCreate(RepoDetailsActivity.kt:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I even searched for converting all nulls into Strings in API request but couldn't get any solid idea.

Please look into this and let me know any workaround for this.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably writing `null` to your parcelable here: `parcel.writeString(description)`

You might want to make sure the description is never `null` using with the following code: `parcel.writeString((if (description == null) "" else name))`

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply...let me check your answer and then I'll get back to you :)

Comment: Yay! your answer is working fine but i wonder if there is any easy approach for doing this. Because with this i have to add this check to my every field because i am not sure which one gets null when.

Comment: One more thing..can you explain how it gets null when my description is of non-null type. Even when i am adding this check in `writeParcel` i am getting **Elvis operator(?:) always return the left operand of non-nullable type String** message for `parcel.writeString(description ?: "")`. Can you explain then how it went null. Is it GSON's doing or Retrofit's? or simply is it a bug in Kotlin? An explanation will help me to understand more about how things working here.

Comment: @TarunChauhan the problem is kotlin's Java interoperability. All the non-null safety checks are made at compile time, but they are artificial checks on kotlin side. At runtime, retrofit reads _"description": null_ and pass that to the Java-equivalent reference (because in Java any reference can be assigned to null) that you've in kotlin _var description: String_, bypassing completely the compiler checks, because we're executing at runtime. And there you are, an inconsistency where compiler will tell you that reference cannot be null, while an output debugging line will show you the opposite